# SQL complexe queryget differential

Tags: sql, performance

I have a complex SQL query that should be executed every day to load a table. The query is executed one time for all the data, then should be executed on a differential data of one day.
My question is what is the best performante way to load the data, I have to solutions :

1. Execute the query upon all the data base with a where query to take just the changed data.
2. Build a copy of the source tables that would be truncated every time and loaded just with the differential of data, and then execute the query upon these tables.

Comment: What DBMS and storage engines are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0):

The performance characteristics of a query depend **heavily** on which DBMS and on the physical data model (indexes, statistics, etc.).  Very little can be said that's generally applicable to answer that question.

With good indexing, etc. (whatever that exactly means for the DBMS you're using) you can get very good performance just querying the changed data (provided there's a simple, index-able expression for "data that has changed").

While I would strongly suspect that you'd technically get "the fastest" performance *for that query* by loading the data into a table that contains only the deltas, it may not save enough performance to offset the costs, which include:

- It's more complex: more tables to maintain, more scripts to move data around, ...
- The act of *adding new data* is made less efficient, because you have to write it twice (once to the incremental table, and once - either at the same time or later - to the table where historical data is accumulated

Comment: I have a readonly right on the source database, I did a test to take the delta of 30 days...it take a long time: where 
DATEDIFF(d,CC.UPDATE_DT, getdate()) <= 30

Comment: Ok.  Well, that doesn't change anything.  Since I don't know your data volume or what you consider "a long time", I can only say that *generally* databases can handle data faster than most people expect; meaning the most likely problem is that the table's physical model isn't optimal for that query.  You could try running an explain plan on the query and see if it does a full table scan vs. an index scan.  Your options are to work with a DBA to optimize that query, or endure the costs of maintaining a separate  table (which presumably *still* means you'll have to work with a DBA).